# How to upload the project to a particular tag?

Tags: git, github

I have two branches, `MASTER` and `FRONTEND-DEV`) and I have a tag called `V.1.0.0-HOMO`!

This tag was created after I uploaded the files to my `FRONTEND-DEV` branch and I would like to leave it specific to this branch and insert certain files into it.

How do I make this tag specific to the `FRONTEND-DEV` branch and insert the particular files in this tag?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's tagging system doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. A tag isn't a thing that exists independently that you can put things into; it's an immutable¹ pointer to a specific commit.

Generally speaking, to create and publish a tag you would

1. Create a commit on your local machine that contains the files you want to tag
2. Add an annotated tag to that commit on your local machine, e.g.

   ```
   git tag -a V.1.0.0-HOMO
   ```

   and add a commit message when prompted
3. Push your branch and tags to your shared repository

   ```
   git push
   git push V.1.0.0-HOMO  # or git push --tags to push all tags
   ```

Files must first be committed and the *commit* is then tagged.

---

Side note: Branch and tag names are normally case-sensitive when working with Git. Operating systems whose filesystems don't distinguish between letter casing, e.g. Windows, can lead to bad habits about casing. It is very common to have a `master` branch in Git, but relatively uncommon to have a `MASTER` branch. Windows will treat these as the same but all other major operating systems treats them differently.

---

¹Technically tags can be mutated but they aren't meant to be. Especially if you've shared your tag, e.g. by publishing it on GitHub, I *strongly* advise you not to move it. Instead, create a commit with the content you wish to tag and add a new tag, e.g. `V.1.0.1-HOMO`.